# SQL Error (1060): Duplicate column name 'CashMoney'

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Getting an error on my Vilayer DayZ Overpoch Server when running a query in HeidiSQL. It's the:  `SQL Error (1060): Duplicate column name 'CashMoney' */`

my Query Code is:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `banking_data`;

CREATE TABLE `banking_data` (
  `PlayerUID` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PlayerName` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Null',
  `BankSaldo` bigint(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastUpdated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `character_data` ADD CashMoney int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER PlayerUID;
```

It stops after this and I don't see another 'cashMoney' column being there but the error still remains.

Comment: What columns are already in `character_data`?  Your `create` is for a different table.

Comment: After running the Query (it's not written by me but my someone who made his script open source and this didn't seem to be an issue to anyone who's commented on his foumthread.) I have following columns: CharacterID, PlayerUID, CashMoney, InstanceID, Datestamp, LastLogin, Inventory, Backpack, Worldspace, Medical, Alive, Generation, LastAte, LastDrank, KillsZ, HeadshotsZ, DistanceFood, Duration, CurrentState, KillsH, Model, KillsB, Humanity and Infected.

Comment: Well, if you're trying to add `CashMoney` with your `alter` statement to a table that already has a column called `CashMoney`, that's why you're getting the error.  Do you really want to create a new column, or do you want to alter the one that's already in the table?

Comment: I guess I want to alter the one that's already in there. There's no data in it yet so I dont think that matters. I'll figure out how to delete the one, which is already there and rerun the Query, maybe that'll help. Thanks a lot